# AWS lambda : PortScannerError: 'nmap program was not found in path'

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

When I'm running nmap from AWS lambda function, I'm getting below mentioned error.

```
[ERROR] PortScannerError: 'nmap program was not found in path. PATH is : /var/lang/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin/:/bin:/opt/bin'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.7/imp.py", line 234, in load_module
    return load_source(name, filename, file)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.7/imp.py", line 171, in load_source
    module = _load(spec)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 696, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 38, in <module>
    nmScan = nmap.PortScanner()
  File "/var/task/nmap/nmap.py", line 134, in __init__
    os.getenv('PATH')
```

Please help me solve this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lambda environment does not have `nmap`. Probably the easiest way to make use of it would be to deploy your function as [Lambda container image](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-create.html). You would construct your own image with would come with `nmap`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I created the container image and install the nmap in it but still I'm getting the same error while running from Lambda. When I run the script from the container it is running fine. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: @Rukender You have to use your container only now. Deploy it as lambda function as in the linked docs.

Comment: I have deployed the same container in ECR  and using continer in lambda function. But still this is giving me the same error.

Comment: @Rukender Maybe something wrong with container. Containers for lambda require special preparation and setup. I would suggest making new question with relevant details.

Comment: I have installed the nmap as well and I do the same while running the container in exec mode it runs the script file but while running it from lambda function still throwing the same error not sure how to solve this.